# How to show a footer view with custom text at the end of the UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, tablefooterview

I have a UITableView to display search results. The user loads more results by scrolling to the end.  When server has no more results, I want to show a text at the end of the tableview, that says "No more search results".  I tried following code, but it is not working.  Any suggestions on what is happening will be greatly appreciated.

```
UILabel *endLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
endLabel.text = @"No more results to display";
[endLabel sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = endLabel;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to reload the table to add a table footer. Make sure the label is setup properly. Verify its frame. Try setting the label's colors and font.

Comment: @MichaelFourre That is the footer of every section not tableView.

Comment: @MichaelFourre If OP have multiple section it will display multiple footer and that OP doesn't want.

Comment: set Frame of `UILabel` to display it. use `initWithFrame` constructer instead `init`.

Comment: @MichaelFourre That require too much code and condition instead of that we can use inbuilt `tableFooterView` that OP is uses, this is batter way.

Comment: @rmaddy I changed the UILabel to `UILabel *endLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];` since this works when I display an an activity in the footer view after user scrolls to the bottom and there are more results left to download.  But it does not work for the label. When I put a breakpoint, and do a po.endLabel.frame I get (origin = (x = 0, y = 4699), size = (width = 320, height = 44)).  Why is the y incorrect?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I changed to `UILabel *endLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];`.  Still no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: @NDoc what did you mean by "code you have is perfectly working"?  DO you mean it is working for you?

Comment: @SmartHome The `y` value of 4699 might be correct if the table view is that tall and you log the frame after the label is added as the table's footer.

Comment: @SmartHome Yes it is work for me.

Comment: No clue why it is not working. I had set footer view to "UIActivityController" before. Do I need to do something before I can UILabel? Anyway, I came up with a hacky way to solve my issue. I added another cell to my tableview data source with label.text = @"No more results". But any clues on why label is not showing up in footer, will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following code may help you to solve out problem.

You can write this code to your viewDidLoad.

```
UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
        [footer addSubview:yourlabel];
        [footer bringSubviewToFront:yourlabel];
        yourlabel.text =  @"whatever you want to write";
        yourlabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - yourlabel.frame.size.width/2 , 30, yourlabel.frame.size.width, yourlabel.frame.size.height);
        tbl_view.tableFooterView = footer;
```

However you need to increase the size of footer view of table.

Answer (score 0):

I. Create a separate view in the xib of your viewController. By separate view I mean do not drag the view in the viewController's view as a subview, instead just drag it into the whitespace in your Interface Builder.

II. Now design the view i.e put a label in it that says no more data.

III. Now create an outlet of that view in your viewController.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView * tableFooterView;
```

IV. When there is no more data just write

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.tableFooterView;
```

V. Set the width & height of the footer in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 40);
```

VI. And when you do have data and don't want to show the no more data thing then

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//custom header for footer
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UILabel *endLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
     endLabel.text = @"No more results to display";
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.tblView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    [footerView addSubview:endLabel];
    return footerView;
    }


//Method To Get Height For Header and Footer

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return 40.0;// your view height
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try this code.  Did you mean `footerView.contentView` where you have `headerView.contentView`?

Comment: There is no need to use a section footer. The OP only needs one footer at the end of the table.

Comment: And `footerView` doesn't have a `contentView`. And why is `footerView` created with an origin of `0, 50`?

Comment: And please set your custom view frame as you wish. It is just an example.

Comment: does the method get called?

Comment: Do you find your solution?